# How can my client edit PDF by himself?

Tags: pdf

I've designed a brochure and made a multipage PDF ready to print.

The client doesn't want to be bothering me all the time when he wants to change something
so he wants to be able to edit the text by himself.

Is this possible?

(not much into PDF other than converting design files into .pdf and send to printing)

Comment: @Ingþór, you need to review your questions and mark the appropriate answers if they have one. For more info read this FAQ: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to get the professional version of Acrobat.

Using that, you can make a pdf into a dynamic form that somebody else can edit form fields or text boxes.

If you want him to just "edit" the general layout or the document structure (instead of just entering form fields), then you should send him the underlying document (word or photoshop). PDF is primarily a print format and designed for non-editable distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you generated the PDF by using Photoshop to save as a PDF, you can give him the .PSD (if he has Photoshop).

Otherwise, try [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/) - assuming he's on Windows, it might be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Linux users can edit text in a PDF document using PDFedit application

Answer (score 0):

If your client uses Windows and he can afford a commercial solution I recommend [Amyuni PDF Suite Desktop Edition](http://www.amyuni.com/en/enduser/pdfsuiteend).

Comment: Disclaimer: I am part of the development team at Amyuni Technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Tell him to try [PDF Pro](https://www.pdfpro.co), an online PDF Editor, creator and converter. Your client can easily erase and add text to a PDF, entirely online.

(I am a founder of PDF Pro)